# Trouble bridging connection between my Pi and my laptop's WiFi

Tags: raspberry-pi, ethernet, network, bridge

I have been trying to get this working for a while now and still no luck. I have Googled and Googled till my eyes hurt and everything I try won't fix it. I have sharing disabled on both connections, but have tried various combinations

Basically when I try to bridge the Pi (on LAN) and my WiFi connection, I get the error message below in the picture:

[image: Error Message]

Comment: The Pi should have a dhcp setup. Also Windows hates not having Windows Firewall Service running when you make changes to sharing options, so make sure it's running (you can disable it afterwards if needed). http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this question is more suited for [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/), but i'll try to give some hints:

- try to bridge connections with LAN cable unplugged
- manually configure IP address for LAN and PI
- use a software like [connectify](http://www.connectify.me/)
- if you have a wireless router, why not plug PI directly to it?

Comment: I get the same message without the lan. What should I do to manually configure the IP (I have zero networking knowledge). I dont have physical access to the router